# Possible values of nullity in 4x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a 4 by 2 matrix. Explain why the rows of $A$ must be linearly dependent. What are the possible values of nullity(A)?

I understand the first part. I do not understand the second part.

The solutions say that the answer is : 1 or 2. But I said the answer was nullity=0,1 or 2.

Why 0?

Consider the matrix with row vectors [1,0] [0,1] [0,0] [0,0]. Rank(A)=2. Nullity(A) will therefore equal 0.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.  It would seem that the book has some kind of typo.

Answer (score -1):

Remember the definition of nullity - its the dimension of the null space. In other words, its the dimension of the solution set to [A|0], which always contains the zero solution. Therefore nullity(A) is not 0.

Comment: If $V = \{0\}$, the trivial space, the dimension of $V$ is defined to be 0. So if the solution set contains only the zero element, the nullity would be 0.